# U-boot build fails - cannot find lgcc / libgcc.a

Tags: gcc, ld

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit and trying to create a Linux Image for the SAMA5D36-EK. In doing so I need the mkimage command. According to [this website](http://www.at91.com/linux4sam/bin/view/LinuxSAM/U-Boot)

the mkimage source comes with the U-boot source and is built during U-boot compliation. But I am haivng problems.

Step 1.

I have installed the following:
    git 1.7.5, tar 1.2.4, python 2.7.3

I have also done:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip textinfo gcc-multilib build-essentail
$ sudo apt-get install chrpath libsdl1.2-dev xterm autoconf automake libtool libglib2.0-dev
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
$ sudo dpkg –add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libxss1:i386 libxft2:i386
```

Step 2.

I have installed the cross toolchain according to Yocto ADT Manual sections 3.1/ 3.2 as follows:

```
$ tar -xjf adt_installer.tar.bz2
$ cd adt_installer
$ gedit adt_installer.conf   and set
    YOCTOADT_TARGETS=”arm”
    YOCTOADT_ROOTFS_arm=”minimal sato-sdk”
    YOCTOADT_SYSROOT_IMAGE_arm=”sato-sdk”
    (and other arm based settings then save)
$ cd adt-installer
$ ./adt_installer   (using the default cross-toolchain location)
$ sudo chmod +x /opt/poky/1.6/envrionment-setup-arm5te-poky-linux-gnueabi
$ sudo /opt/poky/1.6/envrionment-setup-arm5te-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

The cross development toolchain is now located in
`/opt/poky/1.6/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/`

Step 3.

Create U-boot from source

```
$ git clone git://github.com/linux4sam/u-boot-at91.git
$ cd u-boot-at91
$ make distclean
$ make sama5d3xek_nandflash_config
$ make CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/poky/1.6/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/
```

After working for some time it comes with the error:   ld: cannot find -lgcc

Step 4.

If I run

```
$ sudo find /usr/ -name libgcc*
```

I get the following:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgccpp.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgccpp.so.1.0.3
/usr/lib/ure/lib/libgcc3_uno.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s_32.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s_x32.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32/libgcc.a
/usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libgcc1
/usr/share/doc/libgcc1
/usr/share/doc/libgcc-4.8-dev
/usr/libx32/libgcc_s.so.1
```

If I run

```
$ sudo /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libgcc*
```

I get:

```
libgcrypt.so.11 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11
libgcr-ui-3.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcr-ui-3.so.1
libgcr-base-3.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcr-base-3.so.1
libgconf-2.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgconf-2.so.4
libgck-1.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgck-1.so.0
libgccpp.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgccpp.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x32) => /usr/libx32/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so (libc6,x32) => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32/libgcc_s.so
libgcc_s.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so
libgcc_s.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc_s.so
libgc.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgc.so.1
```

There seems no reference to the two versions of the libgcc.a file that appear in subdirectoris /32/ and /x32/

I then locate the following two files:

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf
/opt/poky/1.6/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/etc/ld.so.conf
```

and add the following lines in both files:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32
```

I now repeat the three 'make' commands from step 3 . It makes about 200 or so files (tools, arch, common, drivers, fs, lib, net, test) but then comes to the same error as follows:

```
LD      examples/standalone/hello_world
/opt/poky/1.6/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/ld: cannot find -lgcc
make[2]: *** [examples/standalone/hello_world] Error 1
make[1]: *** [examples/standalone] Error 2
make: *** [examples] Error 2
```

Step 5.

In the Makefile there is the following entries

```
# Add GCC lib
ifdef CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC
ifeq ($(CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC),y)
PLATFORM_LIBGCC = arch/$(ARCH)/lib/lib.a
else
PLATFORM_LIBGCC = -L $(CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC) -lgcc
endif
else
PLATFORM_LIBGCC := -L $(shell dirname `$(CC) $(c_flags) -print-libgcc-file-name`) -lgcc
endif
```

Back in the terminal mode I do the following:

```
$ CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC=yes
$ export CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC
```

Then rerun the three make commands from Step 3 but get the same error

I then try

```
$ unset  CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC
```

and rerun the three commands but still the error occurs

Then I try

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux/4.8:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32
```

and run the three make commands, but still an error

Then I try changing the entry in the makefile from:

PLATFORM_LIBGCC := -L $(shell dirname `$(CC) $(c_flags) -print-libgcc-file-name`) -lgcc

To:

```
PLATFORM_LIBGCC := -L /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32 -lgcc
```

I save the file.
Back in the terminal mode I do the following:

```
$ CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC=yes
$ export CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC
```

Then rerun the three make commands from Step 3 but get the same error

I then try

```
$ unset  CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC
```

and rerun the three commands but still the error occurs

I then change the Makefile entry to:

```
PLATFORM_LIBGCC :=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/32/libgcc.a
```

which finally gets past the -lgcc error associated with the hello_world example, but then fails a little further on with hundreds of failures starting with:

```
LD      u-boot
arch/arm/cpu/armv7/at91/built-in.o: In function `at91_pll_rate':
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/at91/clock.c:45: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
arch/arm/cpu/armv7/at91/built-in.o: In function `at91_clock_init':
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/at91/clock.c:100: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
arch/arm/cpu/armv7/at91/built-in.o: In function `usec_to_tick':
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/at91/timer.c:50: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
arch/arm/cpu/armv7/at91/built-in.o: In function `tick_to_time':
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/at91/timer.c:42: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
common/built-in.o: In function `common_diskboot':
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/common/cmd_disk.c:100: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
common/built-in.o: In function `do_mem_md':
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/common/cmd_mem.c:137: undefined reference to `__aeabi_idiv'
common/built-in.o: In function `bytes_per_second':
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/common/cmd_sf.c:86: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
common/built-in.o: In function `spi_flash_update':
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/common/cmd_sf.c:207: undefined reference to `__aeabi_idiv'
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/common/cmd_sf.c:216: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/common/cmd_sf.c:237: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
/home/lachlan/u-boot-at91/common/cmd_sf.c:237: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidivmod'
```

etc

I then change the Makefile entry to:

```
PLATFORM_LIBGCC :=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/x32/libgcc.a
```

and the same result occurs as immeditly described above

Can anyone suggest how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In some Makefiles it tries to find the search path for libgcc by executing:

```
$(CC) -print-libgcc-file-name
```

This fails if no sysroot is defined, so add sysroot manually. Have a look at the config.mk where it says:

```
CC := $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
```

Change it to:

```
ifdef PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
CC  = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc --sysroot=$(PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR)
else
CC  = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

change cross_compile to another directory, for 4.1.15

```
source /<dir>/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
```